# Is there a word for the grammar construct that dictates whether you refer to an object as "a something" vs. just "something" (aka plural singular)?

Tags: grammar

Take this sentence for example:

> The box contains a key.

I refer to the key as *a key*. Now there's this:

> The box contains lint.

Notice how I didn't say *a lint*. The lint is almost being referred to as plural, perhaps a collection of all the individual particles that the lint is comprised of. To refer to the lint in singular form, you would refer to it as *a ball of lint* or *a wad of lint*.

So what is the the grammar construct behind this? If you're wondering, I am building an interactive adventure program where I have to display the contents of a container. When I put lint into a box, the program outputs *The box contains a lint*. I am looking for some kind of flag to put on the *item* to tell the program how to properly construct the grammar for a particular object. I've thought of *plural singular*, but I am wondering if there's an actual term for this.

Comment: @YosefBaskin This is originally how I had it. It would display everything in bulleted form, but I am looking for a more natural means of describing the contents so that it reads more like a story than a technical description.

Comment: You may be looking for the distinction between _count nouns_, which are individuated, like _finger, bean, eye, car, house_, and which take an indefinite article and have a plural form, on the one hand; and _mass nouns_, which are not individuated, like _sand, rice, oats, horror_, and which take no indefinite article and don't occur in plural form. Search for any of these terms here for more explanations.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is the correct answer based on everything I just read about mass/non-count vs collective/count nouns. If you post as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Compare [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363724/is-there-a-list-and-or-a-rule-for-nouns-that-must-be-pluralized-when-not-precede/363727) (and several others: look at the tags *uncountable-nouns*, *articles*, etc).

Comment: Don't depend on the tags much. They're not sposta represent any systematic categories, and they don't. Just search the site; that'll get lots of answers that use the words, instead of somebody's idea of what other description to use.

Comment: Tags are useful if you want to know the difference between "lint" and "lints" but the only question is about "rice" and "rices". You can try searching for "singular" and "plural" and similar terms, but that's no better than using tags.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the distinction between **count nouns** and **noncount nouns,** also known as **mass nouns.**

Comment: Not the whole story (though OP's 'object' possibly disallows examples of the following). Some noncount usages include the indefinite article ('They took a real pride in their daughter's achievements' // *'They took 2 real prides in their children's achievements'). But covered before on ELU. It's best to check rather than to resurrect what are essentially duplicates.